# How to share a BottomAppBar with multiple pages in WP 8.1

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My app have multiple pages and I want all of them to have the same bottom app bar

Here's the code for my bottom app bar:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" Background="#FF004557">
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBar_1" Label="AppBar_1" Click="AppBar_1_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBar_2" Label="AppBar_2" Click="AppBar_2_Click" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBar_3" Label="Appbar_3" Click="AppBar_3_Click" />
            <AppBarButton Label="About" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay.

When your app runs the first time the first thing that executes is the OnLaunched method in your App.xaml.cs file. It probably looks like this:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Navigation in Windows 8 is handled by the navigation framework which is a lot like a browser. If you call the browser a `frame` than you get it. There is one frame and pages load inside it. You can load another page, then go back in the frame like you would go back in a browser to get to the previous page. And, like your browser has history, your Windows 8 XAML frame has a `backstack` to accomplish this. You can also go forward.

That `OnLaunched` code creates the first frame in your app (since there is not one there by default) and sets it to the `Windows.Current.Content` which is the native UI container for all apps. Specifically, it's the line `Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;`.

From this point forward, pages in your app, including your `MainPage` are loaded inside this new root frame. This is the typical implementation for a Windows 8 app. This changes with a shared app bar. A shared app bar does not set `Window.Current.Content` to a `frame` but instead sets it to a root `page` that has a frame inside it.

The goal here is that the root `page` never changes. When you navigate, you are actually navigating inside the `frame` that itself is inside the root `page`. As a result, you can put things in the root `page`, like an `appbar`. This appbar would be shared across all pages that are loaded in the root page's frame.

It's a clever implementation. But there is a caveat. If any of your pages need to have a custom appbar themselves, you would need to write quite a bit of special code to inject the page's appbar into the shared appbar. If you don't have this "custom" requirement, then this is a simple and effective solution.

**Option 2**

There no reason you can't create a `UserControl` that implements an `AppBar` or `CommandBar` and simply include that in the pages you what to have shared logic. That's probably the way I would do it if there were any chance of a custom appbar in my pages.

Best of luck!

Comment: I changed my App.xaml.cs code and now the appbar shows but the page that I want it to load doesn't show. Moreover, I'm getting an exception error whenever I try to press the AppBarButton

Comment: I'm sorry that is happening to you. With so little information there's nothing I can do to help. But, did I explain the technique like you asked? That is question.

Answer (score 2):

Each Page in a Windows Store app using C++, C#, or Visual Basic can have an AppBar assigned to its TopAppBar and BottomAppBar properties. But you might want to use the same AppBar across related pages in your app to provide common navigation or commands.

Here is a Tutorial [How to share an app bar across pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx)

Comment: I've read those before I even start this question but unfortunately I didn't understand it. I was hoping someone here would make it more clearer.

Comment: @CaveJohnson In this case (from above link), the `rootframe` is inside the MainPage. It's like *Page viewed in a Page*. And AppBar is defined in the outer Page so it is the same for inner Pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `AppBar` code into `App.xaml` and correspondence code behind into `App.xaml.cs` and then include that `AppBar` by its name in the number of pages where you want it like..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp1.myPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
.
.
.
.
ApplicationBar="{StaticResource myGlobalAppBar}" >
```

where "myGlobalAppBar" is the name of `AppBar` given in the `App.xaml` file.